# Solve the recurrence relation with Fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

***The recurrence relation is***

$F_{(n+2)}=F_{(n+1)}+F_{n}$   $,n≥0 $ and  $F_{0}=0 ,F_{1}=1$

> I think, this relation must be solve with Fibonacci sequence. So, how can I solve this recurrence relation?

Comment: make the ansatz $$F_n=q^n$$

Comment: Basic MathJax practice: enclose all your mathematical formulas between dollar signs.

Comment: Here is an elaborated example using generating functions http://austinrochford.com/posts/2013-11-01-generating-functions-and-fibonacci-numbers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear recursive sequence and thus: its characteristic equation is

$$x^2=x+1\iff x^2-x-1=0\implies x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2\implies$$

$$F_n=A\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n+B\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n$$

Now input in the above, for $\;n=0,1\;$ , the inital conditions, and get the very well known closed formula for the Fibonacci Sequence

Comment: [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Closed-form_expression)